# server automatically changes the case of files extensions

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following problem, if I upload any file to my web server it automatically renames the file to an uppercase extension. For instance:
If I upload picture.jpg my server automatically changes it to picture.JPG

If I use `<img src="picture.jpg">` my server returns a 404 error but if I use `<img src="picture.JPG">` then the server displays the image.

Can the .htaccess solve this issue? something with RewriteRule and RewriteCond?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$\.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.JPG [R=301,L]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to upload your images?

Comment: FTP Client. FileZilla specifically.

Comment: Weird. FileZilla shouldn't be doing that..

Comment: I guess it's that specific web server because FileZilla doesn't do it on the other web servers I upload files to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.jpg$ 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.JPG -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.JPG [L]
```

You were pretty much on the right track, except that you don't want to match against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable (since it's only a hostname). I've added some more conditions to check first that if the JPG extension was capitalized, that there would actually be a file there before it rewrites to all caps JPG. The `%1` is a backreference to the match in the first rewrite condition `^/(.+)\.jpg$`.